# update in a function sql in dbeaver/postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I have to update a field in a table with concat() and I'm thinking to use a function with an update sql. I also want to have a rollback if update doesnt' work.

I have this function but it just works the select sql and for the first row of the table "clients"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION value_concat()
     RETURNS record
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
        DECLARE
            rows_affected integer := 0;
            query constant text not null := 'select * from db.clients';     
            result record;
                
    BEGIN           
        EXECUTE query INTO result;
        RETURN result;

        UPDATE db.clients SET clients.name = concat(clients.name, '-US');           

        exception when raise_exception
           then
               begin
                   rows_affected := 0;
                   rollback;
               end;
      RETURN record;
    END;
$function$
;
```

Do I have to make a select sql before the update?

Why the update is not working, should I do a for/loop before the update sql?

The below code returns just one record and not all records form the select sql, why?

```
  EXECUTE query INTO result;
  RETURN result;
```

Comment: `result record` declares a variable `result` that is a type `record`. A record is a single row of data. So you are executing a SELECT and returning a single record. This is similar to something like `SELECT * FROM db.clients LIMIT 1`. Is there a reason you need to perform a `SELECT` here? Do you, the caller of this function, want to see the table before the update occurs? Furthemore why not just execute the UPDATE as a standalone. I don't understand where the benefit is of wrapping a basic database function in so much overhead.

Comment: And for the record, regarding *"should I do a for/loop before the update sql"*. My advice around loops in sql is: If you are thinking you can solve a problem with a loop then you likely have a fundamental misunderstanding of sql/databases or set-based logic in general. In 15 years I've only had to use a loop once to solve a problem in a database.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION value_concat()
     RETURNS TABLE (
        field_name1 VARCHAR,
        field_name2 INT [, ...]
       )
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
        
BEGIN           
 

    UPDATE db.clients SET clients.name = concat(clients.name, '-US');           
    
    RETURN QUERY
         select * from db.clients;

    exception when raise_exception
       then
           begin
               rows_affected := 0;
               rollback;
           end;
  RETURN record;
END;
$function$
;
```

> Do I have to make a select SQL before the update?

There's no need to select, it works well. You should check the query to apply where for unwanted updates for other records.

> Why the update is not working, should I do a for/loop before the
> update SQL?

Because you're returning before the update and the rest of the code is always skipped.

> The below code returns just one record and not all records form the
> select sql, why?

It's because you just return a record type. the **record type**  can only store one row from a result.